# Which index in Bitcoin Core is useful for self-custody wallets?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, full-node, txindex

I am setting a new full node for self custody. But I don't know which index I should enable in Bitcoin Core. If I want to make wallet re-scan faster, and don't want unnecessary storage/operational burden, which index should I enable?

I used to believe that `-txindex` is useful, but I never confirm (and now I find this index is really big). What about `block filter index` and `Coin Stats Index`?

Answer (score 1):

None of the indexes are necessary for wallet operations.

Comment: Does any one of them help? I will use Sparrow Wallet or Electrum Personal Server instead of  default wallet function of Bitcoin Core. Can compact block filters speed up re-scan?

Comment: If you use a different wallet than Bitcoin Core's then that's different. Usually this involves using another software on top. Please ask another question if you've got more questions.

Comment: Thanks very much.